# how to use singleton and/or factory patterns in business logic layer

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton, factory-pattern

I understand the purpose of singleton and factory patterns, however I have doubts implementing it. My problem is that whenever I need to call a method from BLL, then I have create an instance of BLL class (please see the end of the code below). So, I am not sure if this is a proper singleton pattern implementation.  I will try to briefly explain the layers that I am using for years in my application:

DataAccessLayer

```
public sealed class DataAccess
{
    private static readonly string path = "SqlServerDAL";
    public static IDAL.IPost CreatePostInstance()
    {
        string className = "SqlServerDal.Post"
        return(IDAL.IPost)Assembly.Load(path).CreateInstance(className))
    }
}
```

InterfaceDataAccessLayer

```
public interface IPost
{
    IList<PostInfo> GetPostsOfUser(Guid userId);
}
```

SQLServerDataAccessLayer

```
public class Post: IPost
{
    public virtual IList<PostInfo> GetPostsOfUser(Guid userId)
    {
        //Sql code to retrieve the data and create the IList<PostInfo>
    }
}
```

Model Class

```
public class PostInfo
{  }
```

Business Logic Layer

```
public class PostBLL
{
     private static readonly IPost dal = DALFactory.DataAcess.CreatePostInstance();
     public IList<PostInfo> GetPostsOfUser(Guid userId)
     { 
         return dal.GetPostsOfUser(userId);
     }
}
```

And, I call the BLL class like this from the aspx pages:

```
PostBLL managePost = new PostBLL();
managePost.GetPostsOfUser(userId);
```

Is this structure and pattern use appropriate? I have been using this for years but not sure if it is effective and correct.

Comment: Since the code is working OK I suggest you post this to the Code Review site instead: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @nothingisnecessary I think since this question is about general use of these design patterns, it belongs here.  My understanding from the [faq](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is that codereview is for *specific* snippets of code rather than "best practices in general".  Perhaps OP can edit his post to make this more clear.

Comment: In your code, I don't see the use of either singleton or abstract factory/factory method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to link below: 
http://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern

I think you are correct. 
Difference is you did not apply abstract class, and you are using interface (WCF-like) pattern into the mixture.

Thank you,